# Downloading of Facebook IDs within terms of service?

Tags: facebook

I have an app where people login to our site, search for FB groups based on keyword, and then download a text file of UIDs (generated by the API, not by scraping), for the purpose of creating a custom audience in the Power Editor and uploading it back.

Is that allowed?

Comment: This probably helps to get an authorative answer, I do not see you are adressing such a question here on stackoverflow well: http://www.wikihow.com/Contact-Facebook

Comment: Yes, we have already contacted Facebook and received no reply.

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to do so, as long as it is strictly for the functionality for your app ***and*** your users that will be downloading the lists of ids have agreed to keep them confidential. These are the specific items from the Facebook platform policy which address what you cannot do with user ids:

> **II**
>
> 6) You will not directly or indirectly transfer any data you receive from
>   us, including user data or Facebook User IDs, to (or use such data in
>   connection with) any ad network, ad exchange, data broker, or other
>   advertising or monetization related toolset, even if a user consents
>   to such transfer or use. By indirectly we mean you cannot, for
>   example, transfer data to a third party who then transfers the data to
>   an ad network. By any data we mean all data obtained through use of
>   the Facebook Platform (API, Social Plugins, etc.), including
>   aggregate, anonymous or derivative data.
>
> 7) User IDs for any purpose outside your application (e.g., your
>   infrastructure, code, or services necessary to build and run your
>   application). Facebook User IDs may be used with external services
>   that you use to build and run your application, such as a web
>   infrastructure service or a distributed computing platform, but only
>   if those services are necessary to running your application and the
>   service has a contractual obligation with you to keep Facebook User
>   IDs confidential.

Make sure that your app doesn't break either of those rules or any other rule in the [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).